# Why intelliJ IDEA dependency scope is "provided" instead of "compile"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I would like IntelliJ IDEA to have my libraries as "compile" scope instead of "provided" scope. This is a part of my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Logging
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.getsentry.raven:raven-logback:7.8.2'

    // BigQuery
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev227-1.20.0'

    // Configuration management
    compile 'commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10'

    //Json
    compile 'org.json:json:20160810'

    //Kafka
    compile "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.1.1"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.0.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.4'
}
```

The scope always reverts to "provided" in the dependency tab which is very annoying:

[image]

I am running: 
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4
Build #IC-163.12024.16, built on January 31, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64

Comment: FYI: I have reported similar issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168710

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a known issue in IntelliJ IDEA that is specific to Gradle 3.4:

- [IDEA-167412](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167412) Gradle 3.4-rc-1 changes compile dependencies to provided
- [original bug report in the Gradle project with more details](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1276)
- [comment from the responsible developer](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168716#comment=27-1954205) regarding "Create Module per source set" option and how Gradle integration works in IntelliJ IDEA

It's already fixed in [2017.1 EAP build](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).

You can use Gradle 3.3 or older as a workaround until IDEA 2017.1 is released.