# New Gradle version creates conflict with depedency

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a simple build script (shorted for clarity) which uses `Guava` as a dependency

```
group 'test'
version '0.1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'Test'

repositories {mavenCentral()}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {gradleVersion = '3.5'}
dependencies {compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'}
```

When running this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoadingCache<Long, String> applicantCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(30000)
                .expireAfterAccess(31, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build(new CacheLoader<Long, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String load(Long key) {
                        return "";
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
```

When downgrading the `Gradle Wrapper` version to `3.3` the problem is fixed but, I need version `3.5` for something else that is not feasible in version `3.3`.  As far as I can understand there is some dependency conflict between this version of `Gradle` and `Guava` but according to [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle1-11-wrapper-dependencies-conflict-with-project-dependencies/2181/2) post - it is not possible.

I know the `jar` is in place + using `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency com.google.guava` shows that the dependency exists:

```
:dependencyInsight
com.google.guava:guava:21.0
\--- compile
```

Thanks for any help

**EDIT:**
After testing on other computers it seems the problem only occurs when I update the `wrapper` task, execute it and then refresh the `gradle` project by clicking on the *Refresh all Gradle projects* button (see attached image). When running the executing distribution script every thing works fine - so it only happens in `Intellij`. I'm guessing I'm missing something in how `Gradle Wrapper` works or when to execute it...

[image]

**EDIT**
Tested on Gradle version 3.4 and the problem occurres.

Comment: How do you run your code? I can't reproduce your problem with `./gradlew run`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `fat jar`? https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/

Comment: @JBNizet I'm running it in `Intellij` through the debug option

Comment: @Algosub no. I can't use a `fat jar` because of other issues this will cause in my full project. But I will test this and let you know if it works anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Same thing: IntelliJ runs the class without any problem. Try refreshing the gradle project from the gradle view.

Comment: @JBNizet I will try that now

Comment: @JBNizet after deleting `gradle's` cache and refreshing the issue persists but since you can't reproduce the issue I'm guessing it's somewhere along those lines. Thank you for testing this out for me.

Comment: @Algosub building and running a `fat jar` still yields the same error when running it using `java -jar test-all-0.1.0.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone else encounters similar issues the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42457304/4890123).

A bug in my Intellij version (2016.2.5) caused `compile` scoped dependencies to transform into `provided` scoped dependencies by Intellij. This, in turn, makes dependencies to appear only in Intellij's `compile classpath` but not in it's `runtime classpath`. That's why when running the `./gradlew run` command the issue could not be reproduced as there was no issue on `Gradle's` part.

Upgrading the Intellij version (2017.1) solved the issue.